# Using Ito calculus to prove that $\int_0^t W_s^2dW_s = \frac{1}{3} W_t^3 - \int_0^t W_s d_s$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, random

I am busy trying to teach myself some stochastic calculus and have come across a statement that I am trying to prove.

How can I prove that
\begin{align}
\int_0^t W_s^2dW_s = \frac{1}{3} W_t^3 - \int_0^t W_s d_s
\end{align}
where $W \in \mathbb{R} $ is Brownian motion, using Ito's rule?

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/596152/532409

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the other author's hint, $f(w,t)=w^3$. Then, compute the partial derivatives needed for Ito's lemma:
$$\partial_{w}f=3w^2$$
$$\partial_{w^2}f=6w$$
$$\partial_{t}f=0$$
Plug in Ito's formula,
$$d(W_t^3)=3W_t^2dW_t+3W_tdt$$
Then integrate both sides from $0$ to $t$ (introduce dummy variable $s$),
$$W_t^3=3\int_{0}^{t}W_s^2dW_s+3\int_{0}^{t}W_sds$$
Reaarange, done. Of course, there are other $f(w,t)$'s that you can plug in.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: apply Ito's formula to $f(x)=x^3$.

> $f'(x)=3x^2$, $f''(x)=6x$ so $dW^3=3W^2dW+3Wdt$

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use this hint. Sorry I am very new to stochastic calculus and think its better i admit my lack of understanding on the subject.

Comment: How do I tie the hint in to prove this result?