# Determine the dynamic of the stochastic process $Y_t=W_t^3, t \ge 0$ by using the Ito-Doeblin Lemma

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes

Let $\{W_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion on a probability space $(\Omega,\cal{F},\Bbb P)$ and let $\{\cal F_t\}_{t \ge 0}$ be the filtration of the Brownian motion. Use the Ito-Doeblin Lemma to derive the dynamic of the stochastic process $Y_t := W_t^3, t \ge 0$.

**Attempt:**
The Ito-Doeblin Lemma is given by
$$df(W_t)=f'(W_t)dW_t+\frac12f''(W_t)dt, \qquad \qquad (1)$$
where $f(x)$ is a differentiable function for which the derivatives $f'$ and $f''$ are defined and continuous.

Given $Y_t:=W_t^3, t \ge 0$. Let $f(x)=x^3$. Then $f'(x)=3x^2$ and $f''(x)=6x$.
Hence, by $(1)$, we obtain
$$dY_t=df(W_t)=3W_t^2dW_t+\frac12 \cdot 6W_tdt = 3W_t^2dW_t + 3W_tdt.$$
Therefore, the dynamic of the stochastic process $Y_t=W_t^3, t \ge 0$ is given by
$$dY_t=\alpha_t dt + \sigma_tdW_t,$$
where $\alpha_t=3W_t^2$ and $\sigma_t=3W_t$.

Am I true?

Comment: Yes, it’s correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Ito calculus to prove that $\int_0^t W_s^2dW_s = \frac{1}{3} W_t^3 - \int_0^t W_s d_s$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907628/using-ito-calculus-to-prove-that-int-0t-w-s2dw-s-frac13-w-t3-int)